# Angular 2 ngOnChange and Input Binding is not working for dynamically added Components

Tags: angular

`ngOnChange` lifecycle method and Input binding is not working for dynamically added ``` Angular`` Components using ViewContainerRef.createComponent ```.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MBYdMP?p=preview

```
export class StaticChildComp implements OnChanges {
  @Input() public value: any;
  @Output() public valueChange:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  change() {
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: {}): any {
    console.log("From Static Child:" + JSON.stringify(changes));
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="change($event)"/>
  `,
  inputs: ["value"],
  outpus: ["valueChange"]
})
export class DynamicChildComp extends StaticChildComp {
  ngOnChanges(changes: {}): any {
    console.log("From Dynamic Child:" + JSON.stringify(changes));
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'parent-comp',
  template: `

    <span>What Parent can see: {{value.name}}</span>
    <br/>
    <label>Static Child</label><child-comp [(value)]="value.name" (valueChange)="onChildValueChange($event)"></child-comp>
    <br/>
    <label>Dynamic Child</label><div #child></div>
  `,
  directives: [StaticChildComp, DynamicChildComp]
})
export class ParentComp {
  @Input() value: any;

  constructor(protected cr: ComponentResolver) { }

  @ViewChild("child",{read: ViewContainerRef}) myChild;

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.cr.resolveComponent(DynamicChildComp)
      .then((cf: ComponentFactory<any>) => {
        let ref = this.myChild.createComponent(cf);
        ref.instance.value = this.value.name;
        ref.instance.valueChange.subscribe( (value: any) => {
          this.onChildValueChange(value);
        });
      });
  }

  ngOnChanges (changes: {
        [key: string]: SimpleChange;
    }) {
    console.log("Changes" + JSON.stringify(changes));
  }

  onChildValueChange (newValue) {
    this.value.name = newValue;
  }
}
```

I have two static component which is added to parent component which works without any issue. But Dynamically added component has problem where input binding are not working and also `ngOnChange` method is not called. I have also update Dynamic component class to not use `annotation` because of a `bug` in `Angular` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5415 still it did not help.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: is it still actual?